# Streaming video over named PIPE with limited "channel" bandwidth

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, pv

I have a video container `vid.mp4` that I want to play with `ffplay` through a named PIPE and be able to tweak the maximum bandwidth allowed by the "channel". Follows what I did:

`1.` Create a named PIPE:

```
mkfifo pipe_in
```

`2.` Send the container to the pipe with a limited bandwidth (150kB/s) with the help of pipe viewer `pv`:

```
cat vid.mp4 | pv -L 150k > pipe_in
```

`3.` Play the video with `ffplay`:

```
ffplay cache:./pipe_in
```

**My expectation**: To watch the video come through immediately but slowly given the bandwidth constraint.

**What really happens**: The video begins to show at normal speed only when command `2.` finishes running.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does vid.mp4 have moov at front? If not, run `ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart newvid.mp4` and check.

Comment: @Gyan, The atoms of vid.mp4 are listed here: https://pastebin.com/U3PWLGvq
I am not really sure on how to read it so I ran the command you suggested anyway, which produces newvid.mp4 with the following atoms file:
https://pastebin.com/wJ2q8DD9
I reran the experiment but the result was exactly the same: `ffplay` starts playing only when command 2. reaches the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video will need to have MOOV box upfront.

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart newvid.mp4
```

Now, you should get as-available playback with

```
ffplay ./pipe_in
```

If you wish to use the cache protocol, you'll need to set a cache limit.

```
ffplay -read_ahead_limit 65K cache:./pipe_in
```

If the option isn't found, upgrade ffplay.

Comment: Share full log of ffplay attempt.

Comment: Share full log of failing attempt

Comment: First approach works well: `ffplay ./pipe_in`.
Second approach not really: `ffplay -read_ahead_limit 65K cache:./pipe_in`. The behavior is the same as before which means `ffplay` will only start decoding when `cat vid.mp4 | pv -L 150k > pipe_in` finishes running.
This is the log I get: https://0bin.net/paste/L+tVEYx2c43jDyE8#7DmJKWsEBsPshoCOgX0rjKpm-/UeaCb6JssoCnS69Sf
(I'm deleting the previous comments to avoid confusion)